# how to dynamiclly change icon using provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, flutter-change-notifier

How  to change icon when the product item was added in to cart? I am using provider for writing some logic of adding items to cart. The function works fine, but I don't get it how to dynamically change icon if only one item was added. I don't want to change all icons when I pressed the button as it does setState method, because ot update all buttons states.

Now my code is like this:

```
    class AddToCart with ChangeNotifier {
    
      final Map<int, Item> _productCart = {};
    
      Map<int, Item> get itemsInCart {
        return _productCart;
      }
    
      void addInCart({ final int id})  {
        if (_productCart.containsKey(id)) {
            _productCart.update(id, (value) => Item(
              id: value.id
            ));
            print(_productCart);
        } else {
            _productCart.putIfAbsent(
                id, () => Item(id: id));
            print('object');
        }
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
        void removeFromCart(final int id){
    //...Some logic
    isAdd = false;
  }

  bool _isAdd = true;

  bool get isAdd => _isAdd;

  set isAdd(bool value) {
    _isAdd = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
    
    }
```

and in my ui I am trying to update the state of Icon when user clicked to heart icon, But now it dosen't work:

```
 Consumer<AddToCart>(builder: (ctx, value, child) {
                          return IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                cart.addInCart();
                                context
                                    .read<AddToCart>().removeFromCart(providerGridPagination.itemgrid[index]);
                              },
                              icon: FaIcon(
                                cart.isAdd ? FontAwesomeIcons.heart : FontAwesomeIcons.heartBroken, color: Colors.red,
                              ));
```

I did as @Tim explained to me, but I got the all icons changed not only one which was added to favs. How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the value of `_isAdd` is never updated at any point in time, so  you may want to update the value of `_isAdd` whenever an item is added or removed (assuming you are taking quantity in cart into consideration) to your cart, though you may want to do that at the state level of the let say `ProductItem` Widget rather than at the provider level.

Typically doing so on the provider level would look like this:

```
class AddToCart with ChangeNotifier {
  final Map<int, Item> _productCart = {};

  Map<int, Item> get itemsInCart {
    return _productCart;
  }

  void addInCart({final int id}) {
    if (_productCart.containsKey(id)) {
      _productCart.update(id, (value) => Item(id: value.id));
      isAdd = true;
      print(_productCart);
    } else {
      _productCart.putIfAbsent(id, () => Item(id: id));
      print('object');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  void removeFromCart(final int id){
    //...Some logic
    isAdd = false;
  }

  bool _isAdd = true;

  bool get isAdd => _isAdd;

  set isAdd(bool value) {
    _isAdd = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for helping. I am trying to put it in the ui, but it feels like I am doing spmething wrong, `return IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    cart.addInCart();
                                    cart.removeFromCart((cart.itemsInCart.values.elementAt(index).id));
                                  },
                                  icon: FaIcon(
                           cart.isAdd ? FontAwesomeIcons.heart : FontAwesomeIcons.heartBroken, color: Colors.red,`

Comment: also s I understood to remove items by id from the Map I should use removeWhere method, but it still dosen't work, I am doing like this: ` void removeFromCart(int id){
    itemsInCart.removeWhere((key, value) => value.id == id);
    isAdd = false;
  }`